# Can you Teleport someone else during Time Stop?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can you cast a Time Stop, grab some items, touch a willing ally and teleport both of you to safety before the Time Stop effect ends?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**

As per [Time Stop](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/time-stop/)'s text -

> While the time stop is in effect, other creatures are invulnerable to your attacks and spells; you cannot target such creatures with any attack or spell.

Note that it does not specify enemies or allies - all other creatures are immune to your spells. If you tried to do this, the spell would just teleport you (along with the objects).

Depending on your GM, you might be able to get away with readying to cast the spell when the Time Stop effect ends.